# How do I send params to a FactoryGirl trait?

Tags: testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm writing some tests that call a FG create with a trait that after_create, makes an associated object. Is there a way to send parameters to that associated product when I make the FG, or do I need to set them afterwards?

Comment: Does [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297357/factorygirl-override-attribute-of-associated-object) answer your question? You'd do the same thing except add the `after_create` block in the trait.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add that parameter in ignore:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  trait :my_trait do
    ignore do
      associated_attributes nil
    end

    after_create do |object, evaluator|
      # Use the ignored associated_attributes when creating the associated object
      associated_object = AssociatedModel.new(evaluator.associated_attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

And [this page has a lot more tricks](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/factory_girl_tips.html)

Comment: ignore is deprecated and will be removed in FactoryGirl 5.0 you can use transient instead of ignore
[source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/527)